# Can I use Siri kit to request information from my server?

Tags: ios, sirikit

I want to use Siri to show some data, it it was invoked. 
For example if I was developing a news app. 
Could I have it such that, if the user asks Siri 'what's the headlines from 'myapp''
It returns the top most headline according to my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually You can't do thar with SiriKit (Intents.framework). The `domains` allowed are listed below (read more at [Siri Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875))...

- VoIP calling
- Messaging
- Payments
- Photo
- Workouts
- Ride booking
- CarPlay (automotive vendors only)
- Restaurant reservations (requires additional support from Apple)

Maybe what You are looking for is in the [Speech Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech).